# Hopf "algebroid" structure of a groupoid convolution algebra?

Tags: convolution, noncommutative-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras, groupoids

To male thinks simple as possible, lets say we have a discrete group $G.$ Then the then the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ (of finitely supported complex valued functions on $G$) has a convolution and an involution operation given by $$(f\star g)(x)=\sum_{x=ab}f(a)g(b), \qquad f^{\ast}(x)=\overline{f(x^{-1})}$$

It is easier to interpret $\mathbb{C}[G]$ as the free complex vector space spanned by $G$ for notational convenience. I came across a statement that says this $\ast$-convolution algebra has a natural Hopf algebra structure given by comultiplication $\Delta(g)=g\otimes g$ and counit $\epsilon(g)=1,$ then extended linearly. Also antipode is given by $\ast$-operation extended antilinearly.

Now I would like to know, what happen if we replace the group $G$ with a groupoid? My naïve guess is that we would get a Hopf algebroid (many object analogue of the known construction). If it is the case, how would the coalgebra look like? Can anyone explain me this structure or direct me to a (simple) reference?

**This question is [cross posed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387279/hopf-algebroid-structure-of-a-groupoid-convolution-algebra) on MO and received a positive answer.**

Comment: The groupoid algebra is a direct sum of tensor products of group algebras and tensor products. Already you can't really take direct sums of Hopf algebras, I think...

Comment: @runway44: can you please elaborate it with little bit more details

Comment: About what? ${}$

Comment: You should reference that this I'd on MO

Comment: @JPMcCarthy: Thanks for reminding me that. I added a link at the end of problem statement.